# How to get Subnet from an IP in Java

Tags: java, python, interface, ip, subnet

How do I get the subnet value from an IP Address.
For eg, we can do below in Python. (But how about Java?)

```
interface = ipaddress.IPv4Interface('11.22.104.0/0.0.0.255')
value = interface.with_prefixlen
```

Output of value = 11.22.104.0/24

Basically, I need a function to convert 0.0.0.255 into /24. Thanks.

**Edit**

-Java 7 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Guava:

```
int slash = Integer.bitCount(
        ~Ints.fromByteArray(
                InetAddresses.forString("0.0.0.255").getAddress()));
```

With Java 8:

```
int slash = Arrays.stream("0.0.0.255".split("\\."))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .map(i -> ~i & 0xFF)
        .map(Integer::bitCount)
        .sum();
```

With Java 7:

```
int slash = 0;
for (String octet : "0.0.0.255".split("\\.")) {
    slash += Integer.bitCount(~Integer.parseInt(octet) & 0xFF);
}
```

The value of `slash` will be 24.

Comment: Is there any ready-to-use library in Java 7?
My application is using Java 7, hence the code provided above is not working. Sorry for never mentioning the Java version.

Comment: @user1841495 Added a Java 7 version.

Comment: Thanks for the solution for Java 7, do you mind to make some explanation? I'm going to test with this solution shortly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1841495 Basically we're converting the IP address to 4 unsigned bytes, then counting the inverted bits (because this is a [wildcard mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_mask)).

Answer (score 0):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) supports both IPv4 and IPv6 subnets in a polymorphic manner.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.  The following code will convert a host mask to a prefix length:

```
IPAddressString maskString = new IPAddressString("0.0.0.255");
IPAddress mask = maskString.toAddress();
Integer prefLen = mask.getBlockMaskPrefixLength(false);//24
```